# The effect of the time lag taken in the phase difference calculation in the double slit experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

In the double slit setup, why is only the path difference taken into account in calculating the phase difference? If the two waves from the two slits have to reach the detector at the same time then shouldn't one of them start out at an earlier time? And shouldn't that mean that one has to take the phase difference due to the time lag as well into account?

On the other hand, if they really start out at different times at the slits, that would mean they have to set out from the source at different times as well. But then they would no longer be coherent with respect to each other, or equivalently, from the particle point of view, not correspond to the same particle. So then what's going on?

There have been similar questions been asked before but none of the answers deals with this issue directly.